# a problem about `not found. \usefonttheme`

Tags: beamer, errors

when i compile  this bellow code with TexStudio on my computer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,amsbsy,amsopn,amstext,upgreek}
\usepackage{color,multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,fancybox,watermark,graphics}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen, % show in full screen?
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{listings,bera}
\definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
\definecolor{comments}{RGB}{60,179,113}
\lstset{language=C,
keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
commentstyle=\color{comments}\emph
  }
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

% reference entry
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage[
   compress,
   %minimal,
   nonav,
   red,
   %gold,
   %numbers,
   %nologo,
  polyu,
    ]
{beamerthemeHongKong}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute[institute]{institute full name}
\date{\today}
\frame{\titlepage}


\section*{Table of Contents}
\frame {
  \frametitle{\secname}
  \tableofcontents
}

\AtBeginSubsection[] {
  \frame<handout:0> {
  \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[current,currentsubsection]
  }
}

\section{Section A}

\subsection{Subsection A-A}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\subsecname}
   \begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{overprint}
 \onslide<1>
   \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/test-image1}
  \caption{figure A}
  \end{figure}
 \onslide<2>
  \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/test-image2}
  \caption{figure B}
  \end{figure}
 \end{overprint}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{block}{example}<1->
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-|alert@1>
    text about figure A
    \item<2-|alert@2>
    text about figure B
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{block}
  \end{columns}
  \end{frame}

 \subsection{Subsection A-B}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\subsecname}
\begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
  \item
  item A
  \item
  Item B
  \item
  Item C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Section B}

\subsection{Subsection B-A}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\subsecname}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  item A
  \item
  Item B
  \item
  Item C
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection B-B}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\subsecname}
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  item A
  \item
  Item B
  \item
  Item C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection*{Thanks}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\subsecname}
\begin{columns}
\column{2.5cm}
\column{5cm}
\Huge{Thank you!}
\column{2.5cm}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

it says "File `beamerthemeHongKong.sty' not found. \usefonttheme" what does it mean?
you can download this file from [here](https://github.com/quxiaofeng/PolyU_Beamer_Theme)

Comment: It means that no file `beamerthemeHongKong.sty` exists on your system (it isn't in TeX Live, as far as I know). You should say `\usetheme[<options>]{HongKong}` anyway.

Comment: You can download the theme at https://github.com/quxiaofeng/PolyU_Beamer_Theme/blob/master/themes/theme/beamerthemeHongKong.sty together with the other themes needed.

Comment: @egreg after download it  how can do with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download three files:

1. https://github.com/quxiaofeng/PolyU_Beamer_Theme/blob/master/themes/theme/beamerthemeHongKong.sty
2. https://github.com/quxiaofeng/PolyU_Beamer_Theme/blob/master/themes/color/beamercolorthemepolyured.sty
3. https://github.com/quxiaofeng/PolyU_Beamer_Theme/blob/master/themes/outer/beamerouterthemepolyu.sty

Put them in the same directory as your main file (or in some other place searched by the TeX system) and type

```
\usetheme[
   compress,
   %minimal,
   nonav,
   red,
   %gold,
   %numbers,
   %nologo,
  polyu,
]{HongKong}
```

rather than the `\usepackage` instruction you have.